# text input not shown with md-autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I'm trying to use angular material's autocomplete component in my website.

in the html code I have:

```
     <md-autocomplete md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in getMatches(searchText)" md-item-text="item.display">
          <md-item-template>
              <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.display}}</span>
          </md-item-template>
          <md-not-found>
              No matches found.
          </md-not-found>
      </md-autocomplete>
```

and in my controller I have the following:

```
app.controller('IndexController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.getMatches = function (text) {
        alert(text);
    }
});
```

as you see i didn't implement much. but if the autocomplete is trying to find something, it should execute getMatches and alert the text.

welp in my scenario it doesn't do anything but printing "No matches found."

there is no text input to enter text to search for.

what am I missing ?

jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/p7wc8psy/

Comment: Add a name to md-autocomplete (to be used on the generated input).

Comment: I added a name attribute, results are the same

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle?

Comment: @iWörk updated main link with jsfiddle url. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DOM you making is correct.

```
 <md-autocomplete md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in getMatches(searchText)" md-item-text="item.display">
      <md-item-template>
          <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.display}}</span>
      </md-item-template>
      <md-not-found>
          No matches found.
      </md-not-found>
  </md-autocomplete>
```

But the function shown below is wrong, because its not returning anything that is the reason you getting  **"No matches found."**

```
app.controller('IndexController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.getMatches = function (text) {
        alert(text);//this does not return anything
    }
});
```

Now the next question what should it return.

It should return a JSON array like below.

```
[{
        value: "apple",
        display: "apple"
    }, {
        value: "banana",
        display: "banana"
    }, {
        value: "gauva",
        display: "gauva"
    }, {
        value: "melon",
        display: "melon"
    }, {
        value: "potato",
        display: "potato"
    }, {
        value: "carrot",
        display: "carrot"
    }, {
        value: "cauliflower",
        display: "cauliflower"
    }, {
        value: "jasmine",
        display: "jasmine"
    }, {
        value: "cabbage",
        display: "cabbage"
    }, {
        value: "peas",
        display: "peas"
    }]
```

What is the `display key` here in the JSON

Since you have mentioned here `md-item-text="item.display"` so the returned array must have the display key which is displayed in the auto-complete drop down.

So my search function looks like this:

```
$scope.myDta = [{
            value: "apple",
            display: "apple"
        }, {
            value: "banana",
            display: "banana"
        }, {
            value: "gauva",
            display: "gauva"
        }, {
            value: "melon",
            display: "melon"
        }, {
            value: "potato",
            display: "potato"
        }, {
            value: "carrot",
            display: "carrot"
        }, {
            value: "cauliflower",
            display: "cauliflower"
        }, {
            value: "jasmine",
            display: "jasmine"
        }, {
            value: "cabbage",
            display: "cabbage"
        }, {
            value: "peas",
            display: "peas"
        }];
        $scope.getMatches = function (text) {
            text = text.toLowerCase();
            var ret = $scope.myDta.filter(function (d) {
                //return element which starts with entered text
                return d.display.startsWith(text);
            });
            return ret;
        }
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/1y1Lnkeh/5/)

Testcase: Type **ca**

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks to your jsfiddle i found the problem. i didn't load ngMaterial in my controller and i did not load the angular-animate and angular-aria js files. problem is solved.

Comment: need help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528680/md-autocomplete-not-found-passing-the-old-values-when-we-submit-the-form

Answer (score 0):

I can't make your fiddle work. I've worked on it to get to https://jsfiddle.net/p7wc8psy/7/ but I think you need latest angular to run material, and that's hard to load in jsFiddle. You may want to switch to codepen or something else.

Meanwhile, I think what you are missing is:

```
<md-autocomplete 
     name="search-drink-autocomplete-input" 
     md-selected-item="selectedItem" 
     md-search-text="searchText" 
     md-items="item in getMatches(searchText)" 
     md-item-text="item.display"
     md-search-text-change="getMatches(searchtext)">  // *********
```

Comment: need help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528680/md-autocomplete-not-found-passing-the-old-values-when-we-submit-the-form