# md-autocomplete not found passing the old values when we submit the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have implemented an md-autocomplete on my site. The search and selecting works, It updates the shown list and everything. But for some reason if i enter wrong values means not listed value and i do submit i am getting old selection value in $scope

Expectation :

if i start typing not listed value in autocompleted then i do submit i should get what ever i entered in autocomplete field how can i do this

For example type M and autocomplete list Mobile do select and do submit we will get {Type: "Mobile", Value: "2400"}

and start type Mobilesss and do submit we will get same value  {Type: "Mobile", Value: "2400"}

but my expectation what ever there in autocomplete while we submitting i should get in console when we do submit

```js
angular

    .module('MdAutocompleteBugApp', ['ngMaterial'])

    .controller('MdAutocompleteBugController', function ($scope, $q, $timeout) {

     $scope.data = {};
        $scope.save = function () {
            console.log($scope.data);
            console.log("dd");
        }
$scope.selectedItemChange = function(item)
{
if(item){
$scope.data.Type = item.Type;
$scope.data.Value = item.Value;
}


console.log(item);
}

        $scope.datas = [{

                "Type": "Mobile",

                "Value": "2400"

            }, {

                "Type": "laptop",

                "Value": "5677"


            }, {

                "Type": "Mobile",

                "Value": ""

            },

            {

                "Type": "tv",
    "Value": ""
               
            }
        ];



        var elementId = [];

        $scope.newArr = $scope.datas.filter(el => {

            if (elementId.indexOf(el.Type) === -1) {


                elementId.push(el.Type);

                return true;

            }

        });


        console.log($scope.newArr);

        $scope.getMatches = function (searchText) {

  var deferred = $q.defer();

                $timeout(function () {

                    deferred.resolve($scope.newArr.filter(function (config) {

                        if (config.Type && config.Type != "")

                            return angular.lowercase(config.Type).indexOf(angular.lowercase(config.Type)) > -1;

                        else

                            false;

                    }))

                }, 0);

                return deferred.promise;
  
  
           
        }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>

 

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.3/angular-material.min.css">
<div ng-app="MdAutocompleteBugApp">

    <div ng-controller="MdAutocompleteBugController as vm">

       
   <form name = "test" ng-submit="save()">
        <md-toolbar class="md-padding">

            <md-autocomplete 
   md-selected-item="Type" 
   md-search-text="searchText" 
   md-selected-item-change="selectedItemChange(item)"
   md-items="item in getMatches(searchText)" 
   md-item-text="item.Type" 
   placeholder="Search states" 
   md-no-cache="true">
    <md-item-template>
                    <span>{{item.Type}} </span>
                </md-item-template>
               
            </md-autocomplete>
        </md-toolbar><br>
  Value <input type="text" ng-model="data.Value">
  <br><br><br>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
  
</form>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are submiting id of item (integer). When you type text, what id do you want to submit?? This looks basically like bad model..

Comment: i am not submitting id ...

Answer (score -1):

When You Select Any Item From Autocomplete suggestion, then it trigger `selectedItemChange` function, and when you submit form (pressing Enter, in this case), it trigger `save` function.

so if you select any item from suggestion at first time, it'll trigger `selectedItemChange` function and update `$scope.data`,
and next time, if you write anything, which is not in model, it will not show anything in autocomplete suggestion, so you cant able trigger `selectedItemChange`, and thus $scope.data previously updated value not update, and now submitting form, log previous value of $scope.data in console.

if you just want to update (override) value of $scope.data, each time you changeAutocompleteSelection, try this

```
$scope.selectedItemChange = function(item) {
  if(item){
    $scope.data.Type = item.Type;
    $scope.data.Value = item.Value;
  } else {
    $scope.data = null;
  }
}
```

and when submitting form

```
$scope.save = function () {
  if ($scope.data) {
    console.log('submitting form');
    console.log($scope.data);
  } else {
    // prompt error, or show validation message
    console.log("select something from autocomplete");
  }
```

**Edit** => to set default value, if nothing selected from autocomplete, then.
pass `searchText` variable into save function in template, like

```
ng-submit="save(searchText)"
```

and modified save function, to set default, if nothing selected

```
$scope.save = function (inputVal) {
  var payload = $scope.data;
  if (!$scope.data) {
    payload = {
     Type: inputVal, 
     Value: ""
    }
  }
  //calling save api
}
```

```js
angular
.module('MdAutocompleteBugApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('MdAutocompleteBugController', function ($scope, $q, $timeout) {
     $scope.data = null;
     $scope.save = function (inputVal) {
       var payload = $scope.data;
       if (!$scope.data) {
         payload = {
          Type: inputVal, 
           Value: ""
         }
       }
       if ($scope.data && $scope.data.Value && !$scope.data.Type) {
          payload = {
          Type: inputVal, 
           Value: $scope.data.Value
         }
      }
      debugger
       console.log(payload)
    //calling save api
    } 
    $scope.selectedItemChange = function(item) {
    if(item){
      $scope.data = {};
      $scope.data.Type = item.Type;
      $scope.data.Value = item.Value;

      $scope.save();
      } else {
      $scope.data = null;
      }
   }

    $scope.datas = [{

            "Type": "Mobile",

            "Value": "2400"

        }, {

            "Type": "laptop",

            "Value": "5677"


        }, {

            "Type": "Mobile",

            "Value": ""

        },

        {

            "Type": "tv",
   "Value": ""
           
        }
    ];

    var elementId = [];

    $scope.newArr = $scope.datas.filter(el => {
        if (elementId.indexOf(el.Type) === -1) {
            elementId.push(el.Type);
            return true;
        }
    });

    console.log($scope.newArr);

    $scope.getMatches = function (searchText) {
     var deferred = $q.defer();
         $timeout(function () {
            deferred.resolve($scope.newArr.filter(function (config) {
                if (config.Type && config.Type != "")
                    return angular.lowercase(config.Type).indexOf(angular.lowercase(config.Type)) > -1;
                else
                    false;
            }))
         }, 0);

         return deferred.promise;
    }
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>

     

          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.3/angular-material.min.css">
    <div ng-app="MdAutocompleteBugApp">

        <div ng-controller="MdAutocompleteBugController as vm">

           
       <form name = "test" ng-submit="save(searchText)">
            <md-toolbar class="md-padding">

                <md-autocomplete 
       md-selected-item="Type" 
       md-search-text="searchText" 
       md-selected-item-change="selectedItemChange(item)"
       md-items="item in getMatches(searchText)" 
       md-item-text="item.Type" 
       placeholder="Search states" 
       md-no-cache="true">
        <md-item-template>
                        <span>{{item.Type}} </span>
                    </md-item-template>
                   
                </md-autocomplete>
            </md-toolbar><br>
      Value <input type="text" ng-model="data.Value">
      <br><br><br>
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
      
    </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: this is ok but when i enter not listed value for example if i type "test" and press submit i need get {Type: "test", Value: ""} how can i get htis

Comment: still some issues there jsut type "test" and submit you will not get anyvalues in console

Comment: type filter where ?

Comment: md-autocomplete search(if we type anything inside input box it should search and show the dropdown list right) not working

Comment: hey @Praveen Soni i added SS please take a look